# Problem with Boost Asio asynchronous connection using C++ in Windows

Tags: windows, visual-c++, boost-asio, pop3

Using MS Visual Studio 2008 C++ for Windows 32 (XP brand), I try to construct a POP3 client managed from a modeless dialog box.

Te first step is create a persistent object -say **pop3**- with all that Boost.asio stuff to do asynchronous connections, in the  WM_INITDIALOG message of the dialog-box-procedure. Some like:

```
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    return (iniPop3Dlg (hDlg, lParam));
```

Here we assume that iniPop3Dlg() create the pop3 heap object -say pointed out by **pop3p**-. Then connect with the remote server, and  a session is initiated with the client’s id and password (USER and PASS commands). Here we assume that the server is in TRANSACTION state.

Then, in response to some user input, the  dialog-box-procedure, call the appropriate function. Say:

```
case IDS_TOTAL: //  get how many emails in the server
    total (pop3p);
    return FALSE;
case IDS_DETAIL:   // get date, sender and subject for each email in the server
    detail (pop3p);
    return FALSE;
```

Note that **total()** uses the POP3’s STAT command to get how many emails in the server, while **detail()** uses two commands consecutively; first STAT to get the total and then a loop with the GET command to retrieve the content of each message.

As an aside: **detail()** and **total()** share the same subroutines -the STAT handle routine-, and when finished, both leaves the session as-is.  That is,  without closing the connection; the socket remains opened an the server in TRANSACTION state.

When any option is selected by the first time, the things run as expected, obtaining the desired results. But when making the second chance, the connection hangs.

A closer inspection show that the first  time that the statement

```
socket_.get_io_service().run();
```

Is used, never ends.

Note that  all asynchronous write and read routines uses the same io_service, and each routine uses `socket_.get_io_service().reset()` prior to any `run()`

Not also that all R/W operations also uses the same timer, who is reseted to zero wait after each operation is completed:

```
dTimer_.expires_from_now (boost::posix_time::seconds(0));
```

I suspect that the problem is in the io_service or in the timer, and the fact that  subsequent executions occurs in a different load of the routine.

As a  first approach to my problem, I hope that someone  would bring some light in it, prior to a more detailed exposition of the -very few and simple- routines involved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the asio [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) and studied them? There are several asynchronous examples that should help you understand the basic control flow. Pay particular importance to the main event loop started by invoking `io_service::run`, it's important to understand control is **not** expected to return to the caller until the `io_service` has no more remaining work to do.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The answer is yes and no. I think I have studied enough examples to understand the basics, but not all them. In fact, as indicated in my post, I get my code to work in both cases and of course, I know the rule that not io_service not return while something is pending.

The issue here is the apparent mystery of that *without changing the boundary conditions* -supposedly- the a function run perfectly well in its first invocation, but not in the second.

Comment: Note that I say "supposedly" because obviously the boundary conditions are not the same, due the different behavior in each run. The point is that apart from syntactic sugar, there are only tre components that may have changed after the first run: the socket; the io_service and the timer.